# Protecting Profile Email after initial Solspace Importer update

Tags: solspace-importer

Is there a way using Solspace Importer, or one of the other data tools, to only update the email field of a member IF it hasn't been updated manually?

We have a client website built on EE (2.8.1) with 5,000+ members. Member profiles are created using a CSV from a database that sits onsite at the client office. It is transferred via SFTP to our server and imported via Solspace Importer.

About 30% of the profiles include an email address. The rest are imported using a default formula. On initial login, the members without an email on file are required to enter an email address. They are validated as members by member number, contract number, etc. We do not write back to the client database. This all works fine now.

This now creates a problem during updates. We will run the CRON job each night. Several custom and default member fields needs to be updated as appropriate by the client database, except Email. So members that provide an email address on the website have their update overwritten nightly by the client database.

Is there a way to protect the "new" email address so it isn't overwritten by the default Importer behavior? I may be missing something very simple here ...

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Email` is a required field in Solspace Importer. How are you importing members without an email address? Also, since the Email field is required, you can't set this field to "nothing" when updating members, so I don't see a way around this: members would have their emails updated based on the CSV.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm running the exact same problem